# Copy docker volumes

Tags: docker, volumes

I want to update some container. For testing, I want to create a copy of the corresponding volume. Set up a new container for this new volume.

Is this as easy as doing `cp -r volumeOld volumeNew`?

Or do I have to pay attention to something?

Answer (score 47):

To clone docker volumes, you can transfer your files from one volume to another one. For that, you have to manually create a new volume and then spin up a container to copy the contents.

Here is an example on how to do that:

```bash
# Supplement "old_volume" and "new_volume" for your real volume names

docker volume create --name new_volume

docker container run --rm -it \
           -v old_volume:/from \
           -v new_volume:/to \
           ubuntu bash -c "cd /from ; cp -av . /to"
```

Answer (score 37):

On Linux it can be as easy as copying a directory. Docker keeps volumes in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume_name>`, so you can simply copy contents of the source volume into a directory with another name:

```bash
# -a to preserve all file attributes (permissions, ownership, etc)
sudo cp -a /var/lib/docker/volumes/source_volume /var/lib/docker/volumes/target_volume
```

Comment: This actually worked!
I initially did a copy as a root user but without -p and some of the containers were failing.
I redid it with -p and everything worked fine! Thanks.

Comment: you mean `-a` flag as mentioned in answer or `-p` ? @KungFuPanda

Comment: @Yusuf the answer mentioned `-rp` originally, but `-a` is better.

Comment: @anemyte man of `cp` shows for `-a`  as `Same as -pPR options. Preserves structure and attributes of files but not directory structure.`
So `-a` includes `-p` . But i did not understood the part `but not directory structure`

Comment: I want to use this method for backup of docker volume, so i can use this command with location as something different place but on same machine, still it will preserve all permissions, etc while restoring back from that place to a new docker volume later, right ? @anemyte

Comment: @Yusuf `-a` should preserve everything: links, ownership, permissions, directories and structure. At least, that's what my cp (GNU coreutils) 9.3 does.

Answer (score 7):

Should you want to copy volumes managed by **docker-compose**, you'll also need to copy the specific labels when creating the new volume.
Else docker-compose will throw something like `Volume already exists but was not created by Docker Compose`.

Extending on the solution by [MauriceNino](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67568671/7533867), these lines worked for me:

```
# Supplement "proj1_vol1" and "proj2_vol2" for your real volume names

docker volume inspect proj1_vol1  # Look at labels of old volume

docker volume create \
           --label com.docker.compose.project=proj2 \
           --label com.docker.compose.version=2.2.1 \
           --label com.docker.compose.volume=vol2 \
           proj2_vol2

docker container run --rm -it \
           -v proj1_vol1:/from \
           -v proj2_vol2:/to \
           alpine ash -c "cd /from ; cp -av . /to"
```

Btw, this also seems to be the only way to rename Docker volumes.

Comment: I haven't tested this to confirm, but I believe you could work around this (if needed) by marking the volume as external in your compose.yaml: `volumes: vol2: external: true`

Answer (score 4):

Try to clone the volume using the "Volumes Backup & Share" Docker extension.

See https://www.docker.com/blog/back-up-and-share-docker-volumes-with-this-extension/

Comment: To create an archive file that can imported with this Docker extension: `tar -czvf volume-archive.tar.gz -C /var/lib/docker/volumes/<volume_name>/_data .`